# karma test controller using toBeDefined failed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

My test failed because it says my controller is not defined. So strange I think I did everything right.

```
describe('homeCtrl', function() {
  var httpBackend, controller, scope;

  beforeEach(module('App'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($httpBackend, $controller) {
    scope = {};
    httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    controller = $controller('homeCtrl', { $scope: scope });
  }));

  it('should exist', function() {
    expect(controller).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

and I have my home.js which is the controller like this

```
var App = angular.module('App')

App.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {

})
```

The error is `Expected undefined to be defined.`

Answer (score 1):

Your **`home.js`** should have dependencies injected in module, change it as,

```
var App = angular.module('App',[])
App.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {

})
```

Comment: wait, ` Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: momentProvider <- moment <- homeCtrl`

Comment: are you injecting moment to the controller ? have you posted all the code here?

Comment: I have moment after scope. now I've included vendor/angular-moment.js in karma config, i got error of `  Error: Moment cannot be found by angular-moment! Please reference to: https://github.com/urish/angular-moment
`

Comment: you need to have moment.js loaded in the references as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132126/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-thian-kian-phin).

Comment: I think in your beforeEach you should inject $rootScope and make scope = $rootScope.$new();